# Updating array length after removing element

Tags: javascript, arrays

Disclaimer: I'm a total noob. Please bear with me ;)

I am working on a little project using CSS animations and manipulating the DOM with JS. By clicking the animated elements, they are removed from the DOM.
When all items are removed, a video element will be added.

The latter is where I am struggling with. The elements are removed from the DOM but the length of the cat array won't get updated, so it's never reaching 0 (when the video would be added).
This is an excerpt of my project:
https://codepen.io/miliberlin/pen/BaawrKg

(PS: If anybody can also help me figure out why .cat:hover {transform: rotate(360deg);} isn't working in my CSS file, I would be forever grateful)

```
for (i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
  cat[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  });
}
if (cat.length === 0) {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/SB-qEYVdvXA";
  iframe.width = "560";
  iframe.height = "315";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: You have to add the length check inside your `onClick` function. On each click, you have to check the length

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's better to work with `HTMLCollection` that is a live view on DOM instead of `NodeList` returned from `querySeletorAll` that is static.

Also, javascript isn't reactive, so code in `if (cat.length === 0) {...}` won't magically run when `cat` is empty. You have to call it yourself when this happens:

```js
const cat = document.getElementsByClassName("cat");

for (let i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
  cat[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    if (cat.length === 0) {
      whenCatEmpty()
    }
  });
}

function whenCatEmpty() {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/SB-qEYVdvXA";
  iframe.width = "560";
  iframe.height = "315";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

> If anybody can also help me figure out why .cat:hover {transform: rotate(360deg);} isn't working

You're using `transform` both in the animation and in `.cat:hover`. CSS declarations overwrite each other. You can move cats in the animation with `top` property (which is a less performant than `transform: translate` but I don't see any other way to make it work with `transform: rotate`

```css
@keyframes motion{
    to{ top: 1500px }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked like a charm and I was able to understand it thanks to your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use `array.splice()` method

It takes 2 arguments. First - start index (i, in your case) and number of elements to delete.

You can read about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```js
for (i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
  cat[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    cat.splice(i,1); // add this to your code
  });
}
if (cat.length === 0) {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/SB-qEYVdvXA";
  iframe.width = "560";
  iframe.height = "315";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: But the last element of the array isn't necessarily the item that has been clicked. How do I differentiate that?

Answer (score 0):

With "i" you have the index of array that you want delete, so you can use method splice for array, for example:

```
var array= ["hi", "everything", "ok"];
array.splice(1,1) //the first parameter is the index and the second is the number of elements that you want delete.
```

EDIT:

```
for (i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
  cat[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    cat.splice(i,1);

  });
}
if (cat.length === 0) {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/SB-qEYVdvXA";
  iframe.width = "560";
  iframe.height = "315";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: How do I get the index number of the element that is to be removed if I don't know which element of the array will be randomly clicked by the user?

Comment: You have the index number in your function. Now i re-post with the solution.